# ReactNative: console.error: RCTView generated view config for bubblingEventTypes does not match native, missing: topPointerOver topPointerMove

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, android-studio

I have a `react-native` project at version `0.64.2` and I want to upgrade to, at least, version `0.70`. I have clone this project from a private repo and I tried to run it but it gave an error. I have tried several methods and degraded my `node` version to `12` and `firebase/message` library was commented than after this app was install but it crashed.

**it throw this error**

> E/unknown:ReactNative: console.error: RCTView generated view config for bubblingEventTypes does not match native, missing: topPointerOver topPointerMove topPointerUp topPointerLeave topPointerOut topPointerCancel topPointerDown topPointerEnter.

I delete my `node-modules`, clear `watchman` but nothing happens. here I attach my screenshot please help me. this project based on my work place.

[error throw in android studio when i run the code .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFz72.png)

I tried to delete `node-modules`, degrade my system `node` version to `12` using `nvm`, clear `watchman` cache. My expectation is at least for this project to run on my system.